# Capistrano - system bundle install

Tags: ruby, capistrano, bundler

I am using Capistrano and I would like to have a system gem install (instead of deployment which is default).  I have tried the following:

```
set :bundle_flags, '--system'
```

However I get the following error:

**You have specified both a path to install your gems to, as well as --system. Please choose.**

Is there a way to set system install?

I am using Capistrano **2.15.5**.